# vue.js select not displaying options

Tags: vue.js, select

I have a vue.js modal that has a select input field as follows.

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="client_platform">Client Platform:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" v-model="addNewclientAccount.client_platform">
                            <option v-for="(choice, key) in clientPlatformChoices" :key="key" :value="choice[0]">{{ choice[1] }}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

The clientPlatformChoices is defined as

```
const clientPlatformChoices = [
      // Define your choices here based on the choices from the Django model
      ["FBU", "Facebook User"],
      ["GGU", "Google User"],
      ["FBAC", "Facebook Access"],
      ["GGS", "Google Secret"],
      ["MISC", "Misc"],
    ];
```

Defined after imorts and before export

I asked an experienced vue.js developer and he said he didn't see anything wrong with the code.  I double checks for typos.  No erors show i the console.  I am sure it is simple, but I cannot find it.

I tried putting the clientPlatformChoices under export data but that didn't work.

Comment: What you provided works.. Maybe the problem lies elsewhere like your vmodel variable. we can't know

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in checking for case.  upper and lower case K is hard to detect for these old eyes.  Knowing that the code was right forced me to look deeper.
thanks @fOURP